# TYPO3 default language content shown

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

If a database field can be NULL (and has no default value), and the TCA l10n_mode for the field is noCopy, the default language content is shown  in a translation even if you disallow it in your TypoScript setup:

```
config {
    sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
    sys_language_mode = strict
}
```

I think this happens, because in \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::getRecordOverlay() (Line 502) the `isset($olrow[$fN])` returns false also for NULL (see http://php.net/isset). It would be better, if the check is `array_key_exists($fN, $olrow)` and not isset.

A good example where this happens is the EXT:news teaser field, but I think this is not the only example.

A workaround is easy: just use an empty string as default value in the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_news_domain_model_news (
    teaser text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
);
```

Even if this is clearly a bug (haven't found this behaviour documented somewhere), I think it will never be fixed in TYPO3 7.6.

Can someone else approve this?

The forge ticket is https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79012

Comment: To get some feedback about this issue and make it fixed, you should post this on https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues too.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I edited my question. I simply forgot to insert the link to the ticket... :-)